# Multiple accuracy layers in Caffe

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to classify a large set of images using nVidia DIGITS and Caffe. Everything works well when I use standard networks and networks I've constructed.

However, when I run GoogleNet example, I can see several accuracy layers' results. How can there be multiple accuracy layers in a CNN? Having multiple loss layers is quite understandable, but what do multiple accuracy values mean? I get several accuracy graphs during learning. Similar to this picture: [image: learning process]

The `lossX-top1` and `lossX-top5` denote accuracy layers. I understand from the *prototxt* that these evaluate top 1 and top 5 accuracy values, but what are the lossX accuracy layers?

Even though some of these graphs converge to around 98%, when I manually test the trained network on the `'validation.txt'`, I get significantly lower value (ones corresponding to the lower three accuracy graphs).

Can someone shed some light on this? How can there be multiple accuracy layers with different values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look closely at the [`'train_val.prototxt'`](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/blob/master/models/bvlc_googlenet/train_val.prototxt) you will notice that there are indeed several accuracy layers branching off the main "path" at different levels. `loss1` is evaluated after `inception 4a` layer, `loss2` is evaluated after `inception 4d` and `loss3` is the loss at the top of the net. Introducing loss (and accuracy layers) to intermediate representations of the deep net allows for faster gradient propagation during training. These intermediate accuracies measure how well the intermediate representations have converged.

Comment: So, when the network is used to classify a random image after the training, which of the layers will be used to decide the class? The deepest one?

Comment: @IgorŠevo it depends on your `deploy.prototxt`. You can decide from which classifier layer to read the class probability.

Comment: Have I misunderstood the meaning of the "Accuracy" layer? It is used to classify the validation set (if that is set in the *prototxt*) and return classification accuracy?

Comment: @IgorŠevo each accuracy layer measures the validation accuracy for different classification layer (output of softmax layer).

Comment: Just one more question. How do I select the classifier in the `deploy.prototxt`? By naming the layer "prob"?

Comment: @IgorŠevo it depends on what interface are you using for classification, the python wrapper `classifier.py` outputs, by default, the last output layer (a layer that no other layer uses its "top" as "bottom"...) However, you can give the pytohn classifier a list of blob-names and get several outputs per "forward" pass.

Comment: Python classifier is deprecated tho @IgorŠevo